# Is it possible to access a DB link through a DB link

Tags: sql, oracle, select, dblink

I have 3 databases `A`, `B`, `C`.
I can only access DB `A` and really want to avoid creating objects there like views, synonyms, etc.
I can't create objects on `B` or `C`.
I have a DB link `A -> B` and a DB link `B -> C`.
User and password are the same for all connections.

The following is not working

```
SELECT * FROM dual@Link_A_B@Link_B_C;
```

Is is possible with the correct syntax?

If it is not possible this way, what would be a possible workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way of doing this unless you have access to create DB links and synonyms on the objects you want to access on B.

Having said that, I've not tried that either so there may be security concerns with it.

But the theory goes:

`A` wants to access `TABLE_1` on `C`, via `B`

- Create a link from `B` to `C`
- Create synonym on `B` - `C_TABLE_1` for `TABLE_1@C`
- Create a link from `A` to `B`
- Access via `C_TABLE_1@B`

**Alternatively *could* you create a DB link direct from A to C?**

Comment: Thanks for the input, had the idea with synonyms on B as well, but as mentioned I am not allowed to create objects on B. I may be able to create a db link from A to C but I am not sure if I am really allowed to do that. Especially as it's more of a curiosity approcach at the end